# 30 days Difference on SYSTEMTIME

Tags: c++, date, time, systemtime

I am willing to ask if anyone has some good algorithm (or ways) to check if two SYSTEMTIME variable has a diff of 30 days or longer?

Thank you

Comment: I'd probably convert both to a FILETIME and compare them that way.  You would use the SystemTimeToFileTime funtion to do it, and then just do the math.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would [convert them to `FileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724948(v=vs.85).aspx) and substract one from another.
The difference should be more than `30*24*60*60*10^7`.

Comment: Thank you, but can you please take a second to explain the `30*24*60*60*10^7` number a little bit? Just want to make sure no one gets any mistake on it.

Comment: @AllanJiang This is the number of 100-nanosecond intervals in 30 days. [`FileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284.aspx) has 100-nanosecond resolution, as you can find out by clicking the link.

Comment: I would be very careful about using ^ in C based languages as it's a logical xor, rather than an exponent operation!

Comment: This ignores leap seconds.

Answer (score 7):

As the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on `SYSTEMTIME` says,

> It is not recommended that you add and subtract values from the `SYSTEMTIME` structure to obtain relative times. Instead, you should
>
> - Convert the `SYSTEMTIME` structure to a `FILETIME` structure.
> - Copy the resulting `FILETIME` structure to a `ULARGE_INTEGER` structure.
> - Use normal 64-bit arithmetic on the `ULARGE_INTEGER` value.

```
SYSTEMTIME st1, st2;
/* ... */
FILETIME ft1, ft2;
ULARGE_INTEGER t1, t2;
ULONGLONG diff;
SystemTimeToFileTime(&st1, &ft1);
SystemTimeToFileTime(&st2, &ft2);
memcpy(&t1, &ft1, sizeof(t1));
memcpy(&t2, &ft2, sizeof(t1));
diff = (t1.QuadPart<t2.QuadPart)?(t2.QuadPart-t1.QuadPart):(t1.QuadPart-t2.QuadPart);
if(diff > (30*24*60*60)*(ULONGLONG)10000000)
{
    ...
}
```

(error handling on calls to [`SystemTimeToFileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724948%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) omitted for brevity)

About the `(30*24*60*60)*(ULONGLONG)10000000`: `30*24*60*60` is the number of seconds in 30 days; `10000000` is the number of [`FILETIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) "ticks" in a second (each `FILETIME` tick is 100 ns=10^2*10^-9 s=10^-7 s). The cast to one of the operands in the multiplication is to avoid overflowing regular `int`s (the default when performing operations between integer literals that fit the range of an `int`).

Answer (score 0):

microsoft [advises](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to

- convert the SYSTEMTIME structure to a FILETIME structure ([64-bit value, representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))
- copy the results to a ULARGE_INTEGER and perform normal integer arithmetic on top of that

useful could be:

- [SystemTimeToFileTime(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724948%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)