# How to comapre 2 FILETIME variables to see if a file is older than 30 days

Tags: c++, winapi, date, filetime

I would like to check if a folder is greater that 30 days old and have the following code

```
static bool ExpiredDirectory(CComBSTR directory)
{
    WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA fileAttrData = {0};
    GetFileAttributesEx(directory, GetFileExInfoStandard, &fileAttrData);

    FILETIME ftCreatedDate = fileAttrData.ftCreationTime;
    FILETIME now;
    SYSTEMTIME nowst;
    ULARGE_INTEGER t1, t2;
    GetSystemTime(&nowst);
    SystemTimeToFileTime(&nowst, &now);

      ---compare code goes here

}
```

I want to compare the variables above to see if ftCreatedDate is greater than 30 days old

Comment: Check out the CompareFileTime function.

Comment: Thanks but comparefiletime only compare and says which of the 2 is largest. Im wanting to check the scale also e.g is it greater than 30 days old

Comment: True, but the title didn't mention the 30 days bit, so others with the same problem won't know that this question actually is the same as theirs.

Comment: Thats a good point I have amended the title to avoid confussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ive fixed the problem with help from [30 days Difference on SYSTEMTIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042878/30-days-difference-on-systemtime). Turns out this guy wanted to do almost the same. Should have seen this before

My code is now

```
WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA fileAttrData = {0};
GetFileAttributesEx(directory, GetFileExInfoStandard, &fileAttrData);
FILETIME ftCreationTime = fileAttrData.ftCreationTime;
FILETIME now;
SYSTEMTIME nowst;
ULARGE_INTEGER t1, t2;

GetSystemTime(&nowst);
SystemTimeToFileTime(&nowst, &now);

memcpy(&t1, &ftCreationTime, sizeof(t1));
memcpy(&t2, &now, sizeof(t1));
ULONGLONG diff = (t1.QuadPart<t2.QuadPart)?(t2.QuadPart-t1.QuadPart):(t1.QuadPart-t2.QuadPart);

if(diff>30*24*60*60*(ULONGLONG)10000000)
{
    return true;
}

return false;
```

Comment: Note that this also detects files created less than 30 days in the future.

Comment: Because of the second half of the `t1.QuadPart<t2.QuadPart?...:...`. It says "If the creation time is before the current time, then diff = the amount of time in the past the file was created. Otherwise diff = the amount of time in the future the file was created."